# Created a new project on Ubuntu for windows using npx, but cannot find it after it successfully runs

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

When installing ubuntu for windows 10, I was following a guide that used npx to bootstrap a project. For example I'll run `npx create-react-app my-app`

When it runs successfully, it'll say something like

```
cd my-app
npm start
```

However, when I try to `cd my-app`, nothing is found. When I use `ls`, I also can't find anything. Where are my new directories?